# How can I override the `this` type of an object passed as a function parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to define a function such that the function makes some properties available to the `this` of an object passed as a parameter. For example, this is how someone would call a function:

```js
const props = ['bar'];
myBarFunction(props, {
    get foo() {
        return fooify(this.bar)
    }
});
```

Here, I would want the `bar` property to be available in `this` (normally typescript would throw an error complaining there is no `bar` in `this`).
Something similar seems possible in Vue's [defineComponent](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#definecomponent). Though, I'm unsure how or if that could be implemented in TypeScript or if it's something provided by Vue's Volar extension.
Is there a way for a function like `myBarFunction` to be declared?

Comment: What type do you expect the `bar` property to be?  Should there be any other properties on `this` other than what's in `props`?   Like, maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDgQ1w) is what you're looking for, but I need more info either way.  Please [edit] to give more details, and let me know if my suggested approach meets your needs and, if not, what's missing.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your response! `ThisType` is exactly what I was looking for. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it. The type of `bar` doesn't matter - you can assume string if you want. I will adjust the types as needed. I just wanted to know how I can set the `this` properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [the magic `ThisType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype). An [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) whose value is of type `ThisType<T>` will have its methods' `this` variable [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) as `T`.  `ThisType` is "magic" because there's no way for you to define such a utility type yourself: its [definition in the lib files](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/94f03cf0c6eb5cb3a391e817db9c9a7bb9f1de6c/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1645-L1648) is just an empty interface `{}`; the compiler special-cases it for the necessary contextual typing.

Okay, so `myBarFunction` can have a call signature like this:

```
declare function myBarFunction<K extends string>(
  props: readonly K[],
  obj: ThisType<{ [P in K]: string }>
): void;
```

Here the function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K`, the keylike element types of the `props` array.  And the `ThisType` of `obj` is `{ [P in K]: string }`, which  is equivalent to `Record<K, string>` using the [`Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).  So every method of an object literal passed in for `obj` will have a `this` context with `string`-valued properties whose keys are in the `props` array.

Let's test it out:

```
const props = ['bar'] as const; // <-- note, const assertion

myBarFunction(props, {
  get foo() {
    return fooify(this.bar.toUpperCase()) // okay
  }
});
```

Note that you need a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) or something like it when you declare `props`, because otherwise `const props = ["bar"]` will cause `props` to be inferred as `string[]` which completely loses track of the `"bar"` [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).

And it works! If you hover over `this` you'll see that its type is `{bar: string}`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsBPAIVgDE1NdUAeAaXhAA8MRVgBneTjGLVAHMAfAAoAUPHgAHGDmmcAXPDhRgeCEXj0A2gF0ANJPg4ARgCtlAFQAWWTlaLSQtAN7wdABXgDte5bz8QvAAvsLiAJTKAG44WMAA3OLioJCwCCjo2HhIOHGIRKLMAXwCglHwsfFJ4mB4vDJyCvAAvB4A5Kaw7XrwUNx1qLxJxGQwlFk0orLynAbwrsaCIBi5OKIRC8ZScBjIMPiIeVgFohh2nAB0XTCXGDgAqtLOMADC-SAbEcYh4iERCSAA)